# Can't Discovery-Locate Config Upon Transition to Spring 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

### Versions

Spring Parent: 2.7.4, Spring Cloud Version: 2021.0.4, Java Version: 11

### Issue

My Spring service has been using Eureka to connect to the config server for a long time, but I want to upgrade to Spring 2.7.4. I understand that as of Spring 2.4, the bootstrap context has been deprecated ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=with%20spring%20cloud%20vault%203.0%20and%20spring%20boot%202.4%2C%20the%20bootstrap%20context%20initialization%20(bootstrap.yml%2C%20bootstrap.properties)%20of%20property%20sources%20was%20deprecated)) and I need to make some adjustments to the old bootstrap properties and move them over to `application.properties`.

The documentation for Spring Cloud specifies that in order for me to continue to use discovery-first config lookup, I need to define a `spring.config.import` property with an optional configserver entry ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=you%20will%20need%20to%20have%20a%20spring.config.import%20property%20in%20your%20configuration%20properties%20with%20an%20optional%3A%20prefix.%20for%20example%2C%20spring.config.import%3Doptional%3Aconfigserver%3A.)). Since I'm also using Vault, I define the property as follows:

```
spring.config.import = optional:configserver:placeholder,vault://<my-generic-backend>/dev
```

Next, I need to define the following properties ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=If-,you%20prefer%20to%20use,setting%20spring.application.name)). These properties were already defined in my old `bootstrap.properties`, so all I need to do is copy and paste.

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId = config-server
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = <my-eureka-url>
```

Unless I'm missing something, these are all the steps I need to take in order to upgrade to 2.7.4. However, when I run the Spring service, it complains that it can't find the config server (via Eureka, or via URL), then it registers successfully with Eureka, and then continues trying and failing to find the config server.

Here is some of the output of the program:

```
> Running with Spring Boot v2.7.4, Spring v5.3.23
> Could not locate configserver via discovery: No instances found of configserver (config-server)
> Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@2aa6311a uris = array<String>['placeholder'], optional = true, profiles = list['local']]): Invalid URL: placeholder
...
> DiscoveryClient_<my-project-name>/local - registration status: 204
```

I understand why it's failing to find a config server at URL: `placeholder` since that's not a valid URL, but I don't understand how the service can successfully register with Eureka yet not be able to find the config server. I know the service is registered because the output of the program says it registered correctly (and I can see it in the registry), and I know that the config server has the correct entity ID (config-server) because it was copied and pasted from the old bootstrap (and I can see config-server in the registry).

### Workaround with Hardcoded URL

When I hardcode the config server URL like this (and set `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled` to false), the config is loaded properly from the server:

```
spring.config.import=configserver:https://<my-hardcoded-config-url>.com,vault://<my-generic-backend>/dev
```

### Workaround with Bootstrap

It's possible to return to using the bootstrap context and still use Spring 2.7.4 with discovery-first config lookup by adding the "spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap" dependency. So I added the dependency to my POM and moved these properties back to `bootstrap.properties` from `application.properties`.

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=config-server
```

I moved the Vault and Eureka properties back into `bootstrap.properties` as well. The new `application.properties` now contains no values relating to Eureka, Vault, and Cloud Config.

When I run the service, it does indeed find the address for the config server through Eureka, as expected (although it fails to connect because it's the internal address and I'm running locally).

### Conclusion

While these are valid workarounds, it's frustrating to not be able to have a dynamic URL for the config server (as is the entire point of using Eureka). Right now, it looks like my choices are either to use a hard-coded URL and risk having to change every property file, or use a deprecated behavior that Spring documentation specifically disfavors ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=spring%20cloud%20vault%20favors%20spring%20boot%E2%80%99s%20config%20data%20api)).

I would appreciate any guidance you have on the issue, and I thank you in advance.

Comment: bootstrap is not deprecated, just not the default anymore. I'll see if I can replicate the issue

Comment: Have you tried just `optional:configserver:`?

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb for the help! Bootstrap context is indeed deprecated. Here is a quote from the documentation: "bootstrap context initialization of property sources was deprecated" ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#:~:text=with%20spring%20cloud%20vault%203.0%20and%20spring%20boot%202.4%2C%20the%20bootstrap%20context%20initialization)).

When I use `optional:configserver:`, the discovery still fails, followed by a failure to find a config server at `http://localhost:8888` (the default config server address) instead of at `placeholder`.

Comment: I'm the lead of the spring cloud core team. That documentation is wrong and needs to be fixed. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Oh!! Wow. Well! Thank you! The whole reason I wanted to move away from the bootstrap context was because I didn't want to use deprecated behavior. Is there any reason at this point not to just add the bootstrap dependency since I'm having so much trouble?